# Boolean("false") returns true.. any alternative?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am using jquery to write true and false strings to data- html attributes. However when I write false to one of the attributes, and then check it it false, it returns true. I also read online that it supposed to do that, which really makes no sense at all.

Does anyone have an alternative? Any help would be really appreciated!

```
(function() {
    // $(".opt-header").click(function () {
    $(document).on("click", ".opt-header", function() {
        console.log($(this).attr("data-is-panel-activated"));
        var is_activate = Boolean($(this).attr("data-is-panel-activated"));
        $(this).siblings(":not(.opt-group-toggle)").slideToggle(300);
        console.log(is_activate);
        if (is_activate) {
            $(this).find(".fa-angle-right").replaceWith("<i class='fa fa-angle-down'></i>");
            $(this).attr("data-is-panel-activated", "false");
        } else {
            $(this).attr("data-is-panel-activated", "true");
            $(this).find(".fa-angle-down").replaceWith("<i class='fa fa-angle-right'></i>");
        }
    })
})();
```

Comment: because the string `'false'` is truthy, why can't you just check `var is_activate =    $(this).attr("data-is-panel-activated") !== 'false';`

Comment: `JSON.parse("false")`

Comment: Why do you write strings to attrs instead of booleans to data?

Comment: If you use `.data("is-panel-activated")` jQuery should convert the string attribute `"false"` to the boolean value `false`. Note that setting values with [`.data()`](http://api.jquery.com/data/) does *not* create an html attribute (which in most cases is a *good* thing), but `.data()` can be used to read html `data-` attributes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Boolean('false')` will return `true` because the string `'false'` is truthy.

You could just run a check to see if the string equals 'false':

```
if ($(this).attr("data-is-panel-activated") === 'false') {
   .....
}
```

Comment: Yes thats what I ended up doing. I just wanted to see if there was any other way to parse a boolean. Thanks for the suggestion :)

Answer (score 0):

The simplest fix would be:

```
var is_activate = $(this).attr("data-is-panel-activated") !== "false";
```

or

```
var is_activate = $(this).attr("data-is-panel-activated") === "true";
```

depending on which semantics makes more sense for your code.

Comment: Note that the operators equality comparison operators (`==`,`!=`,`<`,`>`.. etc.) return boolean values